# How to duplicate a list view with Sharepoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

I need to create a bunch of complex but similar views in SharePoint Designer.
I did not find a way to copy a view or create a view based on an existing one like it is possible in the web interface.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the view and doing a "save as" works.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need Designer for this.

On your SP site, in the browser:

1. Navigate to your list
2. Open your view selector dropdown
3. Go to *Create View*
4. Rather than selecting a view type, underneath that, look in *Start from an existing view*
5. Select the view you already have that you want to base your new view on
6. Modify as needed
7. Save
8. Done :)

Designer has it's advantages, but I find that in most cases it's much easier to build and manage your site in the browser, Designer is best for wide area managing and creating workflows

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to open your list in Sharepoint Designer, and then do 'Export Sharepoint List'. This will end up creating another list, and you can access it from your sharepoint website under Lists.